# How can I get the last column from this list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-slicing

I want to find an expression for the rightmost column in my numpy array.

It contains a number and a tuple. Here is one element from it:

```
    str(my_list[0]) ='[0.04715440011642294\n 
                      (array([-0.50099999,  0.056     ,  1.61699998]),
                      0.046637045285032784)]'
```

I'm not sure how best to format this, but I can at least be clear that the \n separates elements, so that my_list[0] contains two elements: 0.04715440011642294 and (array([-0.50099999,  0.056     ,  1.61699998]),
                          0.046637045285032784).

What I want is the column containing all the second elements from inside the tuple.
So, for example, if the second element is

```
str(my_list[1]) = '[0.04740093197112796\n
                   (array([-0.505     ,  0.058     ,  1.61699998]),
                   0.047308142646754925)]'
```

then I want

```
 [0.046637045285032784, 0.047308142646754925]
```

If I try `str(my_list[:, 1::][0])` I am able to get the tuple alone:

`'[(array([-0.50099999,  0.056     ,  1.61699998]), 0.046637045285032784)]'`

However, when I try to access the second column of the tuple using the same technique I used to get the second column of my list, it doesn't work.

`my_list[:, 1::][:, 1::]` has the right length but is full of empty elements. 
I have made many attempts to get the syntax right, but I cannot for the life of me extract the column I want. This is especially frustrating because I can easily type `my_list[:-1, 1::][0][0][1]` and get the first element of the column I want. Surely if I can get one element, I should be able to find an expression for the column?

Comment: `my_list` isn't a list because lists don't support tuples as indexes, like `my_list[:, 1::]`. I suspect it's a NumPy array, but I'm not sure why it would have a tuple as one of its elements...

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is indeed a numpy.ndarray

Comment: To confirm: numpy ndarrays can only see a tuple as one element? That would explain my problem.

Comment: Of course, just like you say here: "`my_list[0]` contains _two elements_: `0.04715440011642294` and `(array([-0.50099999, 0.056 , 1.61699998]), 0.046637045285032784)`". Any collection will see a tuple (or a list, or a set, or any other collection) as one element.

Comment: What is `my_list.shape` and `my_list.dtype`? Looks like you have an object dtype array - possibly 2d.  But it contains numbers and at least one array.  How did you construct this array?  What did you intend to get?  A (n,m) shaped array of dtype float?

Answer (score 1):

I can recreate your `my_list[0]` with:

```
In [73]: x =np.array([0.04715440011642294, (np.array([-0.50099999,  0.056     ,  1.61699998]), 0.046637045285032784)])                                                                                           

In [75]: print(x)                                                                                            
[0.04715440011642294
 (array([-0.50099999,  0.056     ,  1.61699998]), 0.046637045285032784)]
In [76]: x.shape, x.dtype                                                                                    
Out[76]: ((2,), dtype('O'))
```

This is a 2 element object dtype array.  Similarly for the 2nd array:

```
In [77]: y=np.array([0.04740093197112796, 
    ...:                    (np.array([-0.505     ,  0.058     ,  1.61699998]), 
    ...:                    0.047308142646754925)])
```

and join them into one array:

```
In [78]: xy = np.array((x,y))                                                                                
In [79]: xy                                                                                                  
Out[79]: 
array([[0.04715440011642294,
        (array([-0.50099999,  0.056     ,  1.61699998]), 0.046637045285032784)],
       [0.04740093197112796,
        (array([-0.505     ,  0.058     ,  1.61699998]), 0.047308142646754925)]],
      dtype=object)

In [82]: xy.shape, xy.dtype                                                                                  
Out[82]: ((2, 2), dtype('O'))
```

The first column:

```
In [83]: xy[:,0]                                                                                             
Out[83]: array([0.04715440011642294, 0.04740093197112796], dtype=object)
```

The second column

```
In [84]: xy[:,1]                                                                                             
Out[84]: 
array([(array([-0.50099999,  0.056     ,  1.61699998]), 0.046637045285032784),
       (array([-0.505     ,  0.058     ,  1.61699998]), 0.047308142646754925)],
      dtype=object)
```

This a (2,) shape array with two elements, tuples.

To get the 2nd element from each of the tuples, I have to use a list comprehension:

```
In [85]: [i[1] for i in xy[:,1]]                                                                             
Out[85]: [0.046637045285032784, 0.047308142646754925]
```

You can't index these tuples as though they were a dimension of the original array.

---

If you index the (2,2) with `1:` you get a (2,1) shape:

```
In [87]: xy[:,1:]                                                                                            
Out[87]: 
array([[(array([-0.50099999,  0.056     ,  1.61699998]), 0.046637045285032784)],
       [(array([-0.505     ,  0.058     ,  1.61699998]), 0.047308142646754925)]],
      dtype=object)
In [88]: _.shape                                                                                             
Out[88]: (2, 1)
```

index that again with `1:` produces a 0 dimension.  In Python if you index a list or array beyond it size, you get an empty result (as opposed to an error):

```
In [89]: xy[:,1:][:,1:]                                                                                      
Out[89]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=object)
```

When you have an object dtype array, you have to pay attention to `shape` and `dtype` at each level - or `len` if the level is a list or tuple.  Mixing numbers and arrays/list/tuples creates a structure that's a lot more complicated than a n-d numeric array. Try not to do that unless you have clear sense of purpose.

Comment: Thank you, the part about 
"You can't index these tuples as though they were a dimension of the original array." 
was the thing I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension it is quite easy:

```
ex = [[1, (2, 3)], [4, (5, 6)], [7, (8, 9)]]
print([i[1][1] for i in ex])
```

This minimal example outputs [3, 6, 9].
So the function used is:

```
def getIndexes(ex):
    return [i[1][1] for i in ex]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```py
import numpy as np


my_list = [[1, (np.array([11, 12, 13]), 14)],
           [2, (np.array([21, 22, 23]), 24)],
           [3, (np.array([31, 32, 33]), 34)]]

print([row[1][1] for row in my_list])
```

> [14, 24, 34]

It works the same if my_list is a numpy array.